# Сервер не возвращает данные

Tags: php, сервер, curl, веб-сервер

Всем привет! Надеюсь на Вашу помощь. Есть страничка, на которой есть `select`. При его изменении подгружаются данные с `php`-скрипта через `ajax`. Мне же необходимо получить эти самые данные только со своего сервера. Однако при отправке `post` через `curl` возвращаются только заголовки:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.12.2
Date: Mon, 04 Mar 2019 20:10:24 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.15
```

И никакие данные не возвращаются.

Делаю так, даже меняю заголовки `referer`, `origin` и т.д:

```
$h = date('H') - 3;
    $i = date('i');
    $s = date('s');
    $headers = array(
        'Referer: https://site.ru/page_with_select/',
        'Origin: https://site.ru',
        'Date: Mon, 04 Mar 2019 '.$h.':'.$i.':'.$s.' GMT',
        'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Content-Length: 31',
        'Connection: keep-alive',
        'Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate',
        'Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=ИД сессии из cookies.txt; path=/',
        'User-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.119 Safari/537.36',
    );
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://site.ru/page_with_select/script.php");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "postdata=postdata");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    $string = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    print_r($string);
```

Когда же я меняю `ajax` прямо в браузере, на их сайте, все данные подгружаются нормально.
В чем может быть проблема? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Дополните ваш вопрос, пожалуйста, заголовками _запроса_ и _ответа_ (из консоли разработчика броузера) от рабочего ajax-запроса к **их** сайту.